# how to set an item at index "i" as selected item in zk listbox

Tags: java, listbox, zk

I added a list of choices using ListModelList to a ZK listbox. Next, I tried to loop through these list of choices and find a required item (say "String"). I need to set this item ("String") as the selected item.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this ?

```
  liveListModel = new ListModelList(new AppModelItem [] { 
        new AppModelItem("String", "string"), 
        new AppModelItem("Number", "number"), 
        new AppModelItem("Array", "array")
    });

    String choice [] = {"String", "Hello", "XYZ" };

    Listbox typesList = new Listbox();
    typesList.setModel(liveListModel);
    for (int i = 0; i < choice.length; i ++) {
        if (choice.[i] == typesList.getItemAtIndex(i).getValue().toString());
        typesList.setSelectedItem(typesList.getItemAtIndex(i));
    }
```

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is your original code, copied and pasted to the editor, then remove the semicolon after the if expression and use `equals` to test Strings for equality. The for loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
    if (choice[i].equals(typesList.getItemAtIndex(i).getValue().toString())) {
        typesList.setSelectedItem(typesList.getItemAtIndex(i));
    }
}
```

If this still doesn't work, add some debug code to check if `getValue()` really returns the correct value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
    if (choice[i].equals(typesList.getItemAtIndex(i).getValue().toString())) {
        typesList.setSelectedItem(typesList.getItemAtIndex(i));
    } else {
      // DEBUG CODE
      System.out.printf("Expected: %s, found: %s%n", typesList.getItemAtIndex(i).getValue().toString());
}
```